# GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl) of IIdentityServerInteractionService return null during login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, identity

I created an Identity 4 app server using a template from the documentation. I defined that the database would be initially populated with 2 standard users. However, when I try to login using any of the previously created users, the page is refreshed and nothing happens. So I debugged it and it seems like this section returns null, when it should return the user data.

The code:
`var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);`.

beingin

_interaction dependency injection of IIdentityServerInteractionService
returnUrl = "/grants";

[Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP8XC.png)

Comment: Would you share IdentityServer logs during your authentication?

Comment: The returnUrl should be something like '/connect/authorize/callback?response_type=token&client_id=demo_api_swagger&redirect_uri...'. Can you post your Client configuration, what AllowedGrantTypes does it have?

Comment: the returned null context means the returnUrl could not be parsed

Comment: how to fix  ?  @MartinStaufcik

Comment: The returnurl not being whitelisted for the IS4 client can also cause this.

Comment: Have you ever got that working? What was the root cause? What was the solution? I'm getting `null` from `GetAuthorizationContextAsync` and I'm prepared to try a gazillion combos of the return URL passed in. However, I would love to confirm that the issue was there and elsewhere. Otherwise, it'd be a very wastefully invested time...

Answer (score 6):

`AuthorizationContext` is a set of rules that defines login flow. `returnUrl` is not just an URL for redirect after login but also a signature (think as a client's login) that is used by IdentityServer to recognize a *client* (i.e. a piece of software which uses IdentityServer, don't mix up with *users*). `returnUrl` must be explicitly set in IdentityServer client's records - either in SQL tables or in Quickstart's config.cs where in-memory clients are populated.

`returnUrl` is captured as a parameter of the login URL: `https://myidentityserver.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/myreturnurl`. If there is no matched client in the IdentityServer records, `GetAuthorizationContextAsync`will return null, this is expected and normal. However, it should not prevent *user* authorization if there is no *client*, i.e. a login occurs within IdentityServer itself, using its own UI.

Comment: Very helpful reply, Niksr.

Answer (score 1):

This is in addition to Niksr's answer, which I found very helpful.
Here is a return url for our Identity Server 4, running in local dev, URL decoded and line breaks for readability. In this environment we have a standalone identityserver4 webapp servicing multiple separate web apps. Each is a different client. As Niksr says, the ClientId distinguishes these.

```
?ReturnUrl=/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=ccccc
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsignin-oidc
&response_type=code%20id_token
&scope=openid%20profile
&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3D(~214 chars)
&response_mode=form_post
&nonce=(116 chars)
&code_challenge=(44 chars)
&code_challenge_method=S256
&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461
&x-client-ver=6.8.0.0
```

ccccc matches a value in [identityserver].[Clients].[ClientId]